# How to fix "Failed building wheels for VPython" error when installing VPython

Tags: python-3.x, vpython

Whenever I try installing VPython using 'pip install VPython' I get an error code of 'Failed building wheel for VPython'

This is the problem I run into:

> cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT
>   -IC:\Users\antho\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\antho\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt"
>   "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um"
>   /Tcvpython/cyvector.c
>   /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\vpython/cyvector.obj   error:
>   command 'cl.exe' failed: No such file or directory
>
> ----------------------------------------   Failed building wheel for
>   VPython   Running setup.py clean for VPython Failed to build VPython
>   Installing collected packages: VPython

The VPython said I might have to download PyQT which also required me to download SIP. I did both, but I am still getting the same "failed building wheel for VPython".

Comment: See vpython.org for details on installation issues. Also note that the recent release of vpython 7.5.0 fixed some problems with earlier installers.